# How to use Google Directions API key free?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm asking this question since my Final Year Project requires calculating distance between two markers. But upon using the Google Directions API key which I've registered and created it, the server returns me this result (Screenshot link below, click to see). It does not create the polyline and does not return the distance between two markers.

[ScreenShot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdfdT.png)

If there's no choice but to create a billing account, how much would it costs for a student like me? Is there a student package where they'll provide free access to this API service? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you want to hear but this is the best answer we can provide you.

Google Maps Platform offers a free $200 monthly credit for Maps, Routes, and Places once you enable billing in your project. With the $200 monthly credit, the vast majority of customers find their use cases are completely free. You won't be charged until your usage exceeds $200 in a month.

You can avoid surprises on your bill by doing the following:

- Set a **[budget alert](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets)**, to track how your spend is growing toward a particular amount. Setting a budget does not cap API usage, it only alerts you when your spend amount gets near the specified amount.
- **[Cap your daily API usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)**, to manage your cost of use of billable APIs. By setting caps on requests per day, you can limit your spend. Use a simple equation to determine your daily cap depending on how much you want to spend. For example: (Monthly spend / price per each )/30 = requests per day cap (for one API). Note that your implementation may use multiple billable APIs, so adjust your equation as needed. Remember, a $200 USD Google Maps Platform credit is available each month, so be sure to factor that into your calculation.

Here's the **[pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing#pricing-for-the-directions-api)** for the Directions API.

Hope you find it helpful and good luck on your project.

Comment: But this only applies in the first year when you started to enable APIs in the cloud console. once the year is up, no more usd200 free credit monthly

Comment: Could you please file a support case [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case)? Thank you!